# Solve $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}$, with the initial conditions $u(x,0) = \phi(x), u_t(x,0) = \psi(x)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm just starting my first PDE class and ran into this small example that I am a little confused about.. I was hoping someone could explain it to me. Please note this example takes place before the book define the d'Alembert equation so I don't think I can use that. Here is a screen shot of the example.

> **INITIAL VALUE PROBLEM**
>   The initial-value problem is to solve the wave equation
>   $$\boxed{u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}\quad\text{for } -\infty< x<+\infty}\tag 1$$
>   with the initial conditions
>   $$\boxed{u(x,0) = \phi(x) \quad u_t(x,0) = \psi(x),}\tag 5$$
>   where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are arbitrary functions of $x$. There is one, and only one, solution of this problem. For instance, if $\phi(x) = \sin x$ and $\psi(x) = 0$, then $u(x,t) = \sin t\cos ct$.
>   [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FubyT.png)

Comment: Please type out images so that others can find this post. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hopefully you can show that $u = F(x+ct) + G(x-ct)$ (for arbitrary $F$ and $G$) solves the PDE. Now apply your boundary conditions (you will get a system of solutions to solve in terms of $F(x), G(x), F'(x), G'(x), \phi(x), \psi(x)$).

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of $\quad u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}\quad $ is $\quad u(x,t)=f(x+ct)+g(x-ct)$

where $f$ and $g$ are any differentiable functions.

$u_t=cf'(x+ct)-cf'(x-ct)$

Conditions :  $\begin{cases} 
u(x,0)=\phi(x)=f(x)+g(x) \\
u_t(x,0)=\psi(x)=cf'(x)-cg'(x)
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases} 
f'(x)+g'(x)=\phi'(x) \\
f'(x)-g'(x)=\frac{1}{c}\psi(x)
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases} 
f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\phi'(x)+\frac{1}{2c}\psi(x)\\
g'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\phi'(x)-\frac{1}{2c}\psi(x)
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases} 
f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\phi(x)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^x\psi(X)dX\\
g(x)=\frac{1}{2}\phi(x)-\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^x\psi(X)dX
\end{cases}\qquad$ at $\quad t=0$

$\begin{cases} 
f(x+ct)=\frac{1}{2}\phi(x+ct)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^{x+ct}\psi(X)dX\\
g(x-ct)=\frac{1}{2}\phi(x-ct)-\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^{x-ct}\psi(X)dX
\end{cases}$

$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct)\right)+\frac{1}{2c}\left(\int_0^{x+ct}\psi(X)dX-\int_0^{x-ct}\psi(X)dX \right)$

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct)\right)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\psi(X)dX $$